# Something wrong while deleting data from DB

Tags: php, database, post, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete some information from the database, but when I ask the user to confirm action, something goes wrong. Can you help me?

The script prints the categories to choose if nothing is settled. Then, It asks the user to delete or not delete the categories chosen. In the end, it deletes what was chosen.

But there's some error in the last part(first in the script) and I cannot understad where it's going wrong:

```
    <?php
//If the user confirm to delete...
    if(isset($_POST['eliminazione_conferma']) and $_POST['eliminazione_conferma']=='conferma'){
//if conferma_eliminazione=1, don't delete
        if(isset($_POST['conferma_eliminazione']) and $_POST['conferma_eliminazione']=='1'){
                echo 'Eliminazione annullata';
            }else{//Delete if conferma_eliminazione=0
                while($row=$categoria){
                    $delete= "DELETE FROM categorie WHERE $row = category_id";
                    $query=mysql_query($delete);
                    echo "$row eliminato\n";
                }
            }
    }else{//ELSE, print the form to confirm action
    if(isset($_POST['eliminazione']) and $_POST['eliminazione']=='delete'){
//Array with the chosen "categories"
        $categoria=isset($_POST['categoria']) ? $_POST['categoria'] : array();
//Print the chosen categories to ask confirmation
        echo'Sicuro di voler eliminare le seguenti categoire?<br />';
        foreach($categoria as $row){
            echo "$row<br />\n";
        }
//Yes = 0, No = 1
        echo '<form method="post" action="',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'">
        <input type="radio" name="conferma_elimiazione" value="0" />Si<br />
        <input type="radio" name="conferma_eliminzione" value="1" />No<br />
        <input type="hidden" name="eliminazione_conferma" value="conferma" />';

        foreach($categoria as $row){
            echo'<input type="hidden" name="categoria[]" value="',$row,'" />',"\n",'' ;
        }   
        echo'
        <input type="submit" value="Conferma" />
        </form>';
        }else{//In the end, if nothing is settled, print the form to check the category to delete
//Select the categories from the database
        echo'<form method="post" action="',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'" />',"\n",'';
    $select = "SELECT nome,category_id FROM categorie ORDER BY category_id" ;
    $select_result=mysql_query($select) or die("Mysql Error: ".mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_result)){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="',$row['category_id'],'">',$row['nome'],'<br />';

    }
    echo'<input type="hidden" name="eliminazione" value="delete" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Elimina" />
    </form>';
    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you possibly reduce the amount of code or separate it to make it more readable? Also "error" is a broad term, please define it.

Comment: I  just know mysql_query and the others are deprecated, but I'll check them later if I'll ever find the error. Sorry ^^"

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the query

```
$delete= "DELETE FROM categorie WHERE $row = category_id";
```

is

here

```
WHERE $row = category_id";
```

What is `category_id`?

Do you have a value for that?

Probably you want `WHERE category_id=/*something here like $row['column_name']*/`

Comment: category_id is the column of my database where is saved the category's ID.
However, the problem is when the user accept to delete the chosen category. The script doesn't execute this piece:
<code>
//if conferma_eliminazione=1, don't delete
        if(isset($_POST['conferma_eliminazione']) and $_POST['conferma_eliminazione']=='1'){
               etc...}
               </code>

Comment: then the query should be `WHERE category_id=/*some value*/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help, but I've solved my problem in this way(the script wasn't transformig the value of "conferma_eliminazione" in the integer type):

```
<h2>Modifica o Elimina Categoria </h2>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['eliminazione_conferma']) and $_POST['eliminazione_conferma']=='conferma'){
        $categoria=isset($_POST['categoria']) ? $_POST['categoria'] : array();
        $a=(int)$_POST['eliminazione'];
                if($a=='1'){
            echo 'Eliminazione annullata';
            echo "\n";
        }elseif($a=='0'){
            foreach($categoria as $row){
                $delete= "DELETE FROM categorie WHERE $row = category_id";
                $query=mysql_query($delete);
                echo "$row eliminato\n";
            }
        }
}else{
if(isset($_POST['eliminazione']) and $_POST['eliminazione']=='delete'){

    $categoria=isset($_POST['categoria']) ? $_POST['categoria'] : array();
    echo'Sicuro di voler eliminare le seguenti categoire?<br />';
    foreach($categoria as $row){
        echo '',$row,'<br />',"\n";
    }
    echo '<form method="post" name="form_eliminazione_categoria" action="',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'">',"\n",'
    <input type="radio" name="eliminazione" value="0" />Si<br />' ,"\n",'
    <input type="radio" name="eliminazione" value="1" />No<br />',"\n",'
    <input type="hidden" name="eliminazione_conferma" value="conferma" />',"\n",'';
    foreach($categoria as $row){
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="categoria[]" value="',$row,'" /><br />',"\n",'';
    }
    echo'
    <input type="submit" value="Conferma" />
    </form>';
    }else{
    echo'<form method="post" action="',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'" />',"\n",'';
$select = "SELECT nome,category_id FROM categorie ORDER BY category_id" ;
$select_result=mysql_query($select) or die("Mysql Error: ".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_result)){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" value="',$row['category_id'],'">',$row['nome'],'<br />';
    echo "\n";
}
echo'<input type="hidden" name="eliminazione" value="delete" />',"\n",'
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Elimina" />',"\n",'
</form>';
}
}
```